# Proof that $i=1=-1$( Mathematical Fallacy)

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

I thought of a proof that:-

$$i=-1=1$$

Here is the proof :-

$$ (i)^4=(i^2)^2
\\ = (\sqrt{-1})^4=(\sqrt{-1}^2)^2
\\ = (\sqrt{-1})^4=(-1)^2
\\ = (\sqrt{-1})^4=1
\\ \implies i^4=1 
\\ \text{also}
 \\ -1^4=1
 \\ \text{and}
  \\ 1^4=1
\\ \implies i^4=-1^4=1^4
 \\ \implies i=-1=1$$
This is my proof but I know that there is some problem with last statement as it makes are number line collapse but don't you think that this is still a valid logical argument, if not why?

Is it possible that it is because of 1 is a unique number ( another reason to call it it unique).

Comment: Using your reasoning: $(-2)^2 = 2^2 \implies -2=2$. Of course this is not true: the implication is just wrong since roots are not unique.

Comment: @Mohd Saad. $1$ will always be unique because it is multiplication identity.

Comment: @0CT0 I see you are correct.

Comment: This is a dupe about 100 times over.

Comment: @MartinR Yes it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a^4=b^4=c^4$, does that always mean $a=b=c$?